# 100% height section work in Firefox, IE, but not in Chrome

Tags: css, height

I am using a simple layout with three 100% width and height sections. They work as intended in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome.

Here is the code that I use:

```
html,body{width: 100%;height: 100%;}
section{width: 100%;height: 100%;}
.section-bg{width: 100%;height: 100%;}
```

.section-bg is a div that should hold the content.
Here is the [link](http://madebym.me/test/full-height/) to live example if anyone is interested.

Also, I forgot to mention that by inspecting with chrome tools, it seems that the height of auto is applied to the html element. Of course setting this to 100% , makes everything fine in Chrome.

Comment: Providing external links is not a good choice, you can try setting up a http://jsfiddle.com instead of it, more people will be able to most of times help you better and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that chrome is overriding your CSS right?

So use:

```
html,body{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
section{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
.section-bg{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

To make sure that browsers will not override your CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about important. I will wait if maybe someone has an answer why is this happening in the first place, if there are none, I'll mark your as correct.

Comment: I just now checked on my laptop and it is ok without importants. For some reason, my desktop Chrome overrides the height property. Virus or a bug :))

Comment: Also, it would be really interesting if someone knows why is this happening!!

Comment: Browser's have default Behaviours. And CSS is one element that are included in this behaviours. You can reset all CSS default's using a `clear.css` or `reset.css` that are css files that unset all the known default's.

Answer (score 1):

That is [registered Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346275).
My workaround is to use flexbox next way:

```
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
section {
  flex:1 0 0px;
}
```

and worckaround for webkit:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { /* ...write webkit styles here*/ }
```